# \mathit{\vec{…}} silently swallows up the vector when using latex/pdflatex and newtxmath

Tags: pdftex, accents, vector, newtxmath

Feeding `latex` or `pdflatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\(\mathit{\vec{var}}\)
\end{document}
```

results in

> *var*

without any arrow and without any warning on the console. (One has to look into the log to see “Missing character: There is no ® in font cmti10!” and wonder what ® means .) Of course, the problem can be circumvented by dropping `\usepackage{newtxmath}` or exchanging the order of calling `\vec` and `\mathit`.  However, since the calls to the two macros may be hidden inside other macros (and for my larger, non-minimal LaTeX sources, they are indeed hidden inside other macros), it would be better to solve the problem already on the level of the preamble or in the NewTX package or by patching it in such a way that the user's main document needn't be changed. Any idea how to do this? I informed the NewTX maintainer. (However, he didn't reply within two months, so whoever wishes to ping him, please feel free…)

PS. For `xelatex`/`lualatex` and TeX Gyre Termes (Math), cf. [\mathit{\vec{…}} silently swallows up the vector when using xelatex/lualatex, unicode-math, and TeX Gyre Termes (Math)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643759) .

PPS. The best workaround so far is given by Vincent's answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643761 .

Comment: Why `\mathit{\vec{var}}`? It should be `\vec{\mathit{var}}`.

Comment: @egreg mathit and vec come from the internals of two commands. The outer command (that reduces to mathit in my question) tries to interpret the argument as a term variable and typeset it as such a variable, regardless of how many letters it has and whether it has any dashes, underscores or accents. The inner command (that reduces to vec in my question) typesets the argument as a vector. So, semantically, `\mathit{\vec{foo}}` says that the vector `foo` is to be typeset as a term variable (in the context of some formula).

Comment: @egreg The other way round, `\vec{\mathit{foo}}` would mean: typeset the variable `foo` as a vector or typeset the application of the overrightarrow operation (which is defined in the book I typeset) to the variable `foo`. The semantic meaning is different. In fact, semantically, I have both: (1) typeset a vector as a term variable (rather than, e.g., as a term constant, or as an n-ary operation, or as a sort name) and (2) apply the overrightarrow operation (whatever it means) to a term variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could get `\vec` to forget the italic shape, but a workaround would be to use `newtxmath`'s `\vv` command instead of `\vec`. It's another command to add an arrow above other symbols, but its length adapts to the argument (see section 19.4 of the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) for more details).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\(\mathit{\vv{var}}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's right, `\vv` works; I forgot to mention this. That would be yet another workaround, perhaps, the best one for `latex`/`pdflatex` with NewTX.

Comment: @GeekestGeek and if you're also happy with how `\vv` looks on a single symbol, you could add `\let\vec\vv` in the preamble. This way, you shouldn't have to change anything else in the document to see the arrows appear everywhere.

Comment: I'm also unsure what you mean by getting “`\vec` to forget the italic shape”.

Comment: I remember having preferred `\vec` to `\vv` for my large book months ago for some reason. I'd have to re-check. In any case, this would be a partial solution, if at all, because I have more or less the same question for UTF-8 engines. Of course, `\ifluatex` and `\ifxetex` exist, but they add up to the hassle. Fixing NewTX would be cleaner.

Comment: @GeekestGeek From my understanding, what happens is that when writing `\mathit{\vec{var}}`, LaTeX tries to write the letters "var" with the arrow above, all in italic font. However, it doesn't find the arrow in the italic font. This is what I meant by "getting `\vec` to forget the italic shape": in the end you just want for `\mathit{\vec{var}}` to write "var" in italic font and add an arrow in normal font.

Comment: Instead of the last, now deleted comment: In Lamport's *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System: User's Guide and Reference Manual*, 1994, 2nd ed., p. 51, § 3.3.8, we see a list of commands including “\mathit”, followed by the sentence “They change the style only of letters, numbers, and uppercase Greek letters. Nothing else is affected.” I view this as a definition, albeit not a strict mathematical one. In particular, “nothing else is affected”  implies that arrows, wherever they are, should not be affected either, let alone disappear.